# Best way to compute distance from an input to database records

Tags: php, geolocation, distance

I have an API (PHP) with will accept longitude, latitude, and distance.

I also have a table `shops` that has records of locations

```
id, longitude, latitude
```

Now, my API will accept an input `longitude, latitude` and `distance`

My goal is to search in the database the closest shop to the input `latitude` and `longitude` and `distance` being the scope of search, let's say within `distance = 20km`

I already have a function that will determine the distance of two points:

```
private function computeDistance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $radius = 6378137)
{
    static $x = M_PI / 180;
    $lat1 *= $x; $lng1 *= $x;
    $lat2 *= $x; $lng2 *= $x;
    $distance = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin(($lat1 - $lat2) / 2), 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * pow(sin(($lng1 - $lng2) / 2), 2)));
    $meters = $distance * $radius;
    return $meters * (1 / 1000); // Return Kilometers
}
```

Now, what is the best approach to do this? My initial plan is to fetch all records in the database, and then loop into that, compare the input parameter in api and check it's distance if within the `distance` parameter and push it in an array.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I depends on how much shops you have. If you got 100 you can easely pull them in memory and sort them all out.

When you need to limit it you could select the shops within a rectangle based on latitude and longitude. `select * from shops where lat between arglat - 10 and arglat + 10 and lng between arglng - 10 and arglng + 10`

Comment: may I ask what does 10 means? @Bram

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this recently as well, and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/find-points-within-a-distance-using-mysql) seems to be the best answer I've found so far. 
Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919595/symfony2-and-doctrine-query-with-distance-lonigtude-and-latitude-and-large-rel) is one using PHP and Doctrine.

In both cases they do the calculation on the database side (Not sure how efficient is the query), which will probably be more efficient if you have a lot of records you're searching.